# Re-sizable ads on sides of page without table

Tags: html, css

I created a mockup which includes a content area and two expandable/collapsible ads on the left and right.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">

    <tr>
        <td style="background:blue; text-align:right;"><img src="http://www.citiesmatter.org/vertical/Sites/%7BC2C0C8B8-8BB9-430D-B364-373386495DE7%7D/uploads/%7B42CEE0EB-39AA-469A-8A71-F6733F2A9172%7D.GIF" style="width:100%;" /></td>
        <td style="width:400px; background:red;">
            <p>Content</p>
        </td>
        <td style="background:blue;"><img src="http://www.citiesmatter.org/vertical/Sites/%7BC2C0C8B8-8BB9-430D-B364-373386495DE7%7D/uploads/%7B42CEE0EB-39AA-469A-8A71-F6733F2A9172%7D.GIF" style="width:100%;" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DVevt/1/

Is it possible to do this with only divs?

Comment: yes.........................

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The simplest way is by changing the `table`, `tr`, and `td` tags to `div` tags and giving them the CSS styles [`display: table;`, `display: table-row;`, and `display: table-cell;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Further changes may be better, or maybe not.

Comment: It is not only "possible" it is strictly **recommended**! Layout-tables are "out" since the beginning of the new the millennium! ;-)

Comment: media queries are good for this but it does have browser limitations http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: @user2217162 yes, you can even fake a table using `display`